# How to use `Abs` within `Event` with a function of several variables?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I would like to use `EventLocator` to stop `NDSolve` with the `Event` command

```
"Event" -> Abs[D[f[x,y,t],t]] < threshold
```

That is, I need to check the time derivative of function `f[x,y,t]` over a spatial domain `a >= 0 && a <= L, b >= 0 && b <= L` at each integration step. Beside, it is clear that at that moment the temporal boundary is `t`.
When I run it, `NDSolve` gives:

> "The function value \
>   Abs[InterpolatingFunction[...]+<<1>><<<1>> is not True or False \
>   when the arguments are {3.187144811900335`*^-8,<<4>>}"

I am not familiar with `Event`, but I understand that one should use `a` and `b` instead of `x` and `y` in the `Abs[...]`, because `x` and `y` are `NDSolve` variables and it is better to avoid inserting them in the numerical functions.

Actually, what I need is something like this:

```
"Event" -> Abs[D[f[a,b,t],t], a >= 0 && a <= L, b >= 0 && b <= L] < threshold
```

Obviously, it is not correct in the syntax of `Abs`, how can I implement the 'Event' properly to this end. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a 1D PDE modified from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveEventLocator.html), where the integration will stop as long as `Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] > 1`:

```
eqn = {
 D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x] - Sin[u[t, x]], 
 u[0, x] == E^(-(x - 5)^2) + E^(-(x + 5)^2/2), Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, 
 u[t, -50] == u[t, 50]
}

NDSolve[eqn, u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, -50, 50},
 Method -> {
   "MethodOfLines", "DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True,
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"},
   Method -> {
     "EventLocator",
     "Event" :> 
      If[And @@ (# < 1 & /@ Abs[Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x]]), 0, 1],
     "EventLocationMethod" -> "StepBegin"
   }
 }
]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link to the relevant documentation page as well.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the editing. I have added the link.

Comment: @can `Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x]` represents a series of values corresponding to different `x` in the solving region at the current time `t`. For example, `{u[t,x1],u[t,x2],...}`.I'm trying to check whether there is at least one of those values breaks our condition, so we will stop the integration.

Comment: @ xslittlegrass, thanks for your answer. In the condition of the `If` I understand that you `Map` the pure function `#<1 &` onto `Abs` to give 0 or 1 when the condition is true or false, respectively. But I don't understand that why you `Apply` the `And` to `(...)`? What is the intention that `And` only `Apply` only one argument?

Comment: @xslittlegrass, in my real problem, when I run the `NDSolve` it gives >"The function value If[<<1>>,0,1] is not True or False when the arguments are {...}." After three warning like this, and this line: >Further output of NDSolve::nbnum1 will be suppressed during this calculation. >>. It runs normally so far, however I will accept it if the solution is numerical reasonably. Thank you!